# 2 ajax calls but getting one's data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wanted to call to servlets from my ajax both will return a number i did calling both the servlet but only one is getting called.please tell how can use to get 2 variables values and set them in sesisionStorage from 2 different servlets
also when i alert

```
alert(xhr.open('GET', 'servlet1', false));
```

i get undefined..

```
   function refreshData() {

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var xhr;

    var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr1.open('GET', 'servlet1', false);
    xhr1.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xhr1.readyState == 4) {

            alert(xhr1.responseText + "--servlet1-----");
            sessionStorage.setItem("data2", xhr1.responseText);
            handleReceiveData(xhr1.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr1.send(null);

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', 'servlet2', false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

            alert(xhr.responseText + "--servlet2--");
            sessionStorage.setItem("data", xhr.responseText);
            handleReceiveData(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.send(null);

}
```

Comment: use `async: false` in your ajax call

Comment: question edited : when i alert i get undefined for xhr.open('GET', 'getH264UserCount', false);

Answer (score 1):

This seems due to Asynchronous sending of both ajax requests. You could try adding code like this:

```
  xhr1.open('GET', 'servletname2', false);
  xhr.open('GET', 'servletname', false);
```

which could cause the application to hang or stop for that particular request.

Comment: the second one is not getting called after changing to false

Comment: there seems to be discrepancy in variable names xhr & xhr1. In your first call it should be xhr1.send(....) whereas in second, its shud be xhr.send(..). Correct them and try it out.

Comment: yeah i have used that properly still its the same

Comment: Did you console the results ?

Comment: i have printed on my servelt but its not getting called and not printing only its getting called in the 2nd case with asyn true

Comment: i have edited the question and added my function which is being called

Comment: As you are getting 'undefined' for xhr.open(....), reflects that ur xhr object is not instantiated.I hope you are not using xhr & xhr1 interchangeably.

Comment: yeah i have checked that its correct not interchanged